# "Unresolved reference to 'countmode1'" , Verilog simulation error

Tags: verilog, simulation, error

When I want to simulate the following code, I get these errors:

> ```
> "Unresolved reference to 'countmode1'"
> "Unresolved reference to 'countmode2'"
> "Unresolved reference to 'countmode3'"
> ```

```
module a8bitCounter(inp[7:0], ocrn, counter[7:0]);

  input [7:0] inp;
  input ocrn;
  output [7:0] counter;
  reg [1:0] countmode;
  reg [1:0] clksource;
  reg done, clk, reset, oc;
  reg round = 0;
  `include "countmode_1.v" // task functions included here
  initial
  begin
  countmode = {inp[3], inp[6]};
  clksource = inp[2:0];
  end
  parameter S0=3'b001 , S1=3'b010 , S2=3'b011 , S3=3'b100 , S4=3'b101, S5=3'b110 ,         S6=3'b111 , S7=3'b000 ;
   always @ (posedge clk, reset) begin
   if (inp[2:0] == 0) begin
end else if(clk)
begin
case (clksource)

    S0:begin

      if (countmode == 2'b00) begin
        countmode1(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S0, S7);
      end

      else if (countmode == 2'b01) begin
        countmode2(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S0, S7);
      end 

      else if (countmode == 2'b10) begin
        countmode3(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S0, S7);
      end
    end

    S1:begin

      if (countmode == 2'b00) begin
        countmode1(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S1, S7);
      end 

      else if (countmode == 2'b01) begin
        countmode2(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S1, S7);
      end

      else if (countmode == 2'b10) begin
        countmode3(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S1, S7);
      end
    end

    S2:begin

      if(countmode == 2'b00) begin
        countmode1(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S2, S7);
      end 

      else if(countmode == 2'b01) begin
        countmode2(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S2, S7);
      end 

      else if(countmode == 2'b10) begin
        countmode3(reset, counter, clksource, ocrn, oc, round, S2, S7);
        end
      end
      endcase
    end
    end
endmodule
```

This is part of an eight bit counter .
I used following task functions to write it :

```
module countmode();
  reg reset , oc , round=0; 
  reg ocrn;
  reg [2:0] S0,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7;
  reg [7:0] counter;
  reg [1:0] clksource;



  task countmode1;
            if(reset) begin
              counter = 8'b0;
              clksource = S0;
            end 
            else if(counter == ocrn) begin
              oc = 1;
              clksource = S7;
            end else if(round == 5) begin
              round = 0;
              clksource = S7;
            end else if(counter == 8'b1) begin
              counter = 8'b0;
              round = round + 1;
              clksource = S0;
            end else begin
              counter = counter + 1;
              clksource = S0;
            end
 endtask

   task countmode2;
            if(reset) begin
              counter = 8'b0;
              clksource = S0;
            end else if(counter == ocrn) begin
              oc = 1;
              clksource = S7;
            end else if(round == 5) begin
              round = 0;
              clksource = S7;
            end else if(counter == 8'b1) begin
              counter = counter - 1;
              round = round + 1;
              clksource = S0;
            end else begin
              counter = counter + 1;
              clksource = S0;
            end
 endtask

   task countmode3;
            if(reset) begin
              counter = 8'b0;
              clksource = S0;
            end else if(counter == ocrn) begin
              counter = 8'b0;
              oc = 1;
              clksource = S7;
            end else if(round == 5) begin
              round = 0;
              clksource = S7;
            end else begin
              counter = counter + 1;
              round = round + 1;
              clksource = S0;
            end
 endtask
 endmodule
```

Please tell me how to fix this simulation error. I can't remove "always" because of the "if-else" functions.

EDIT : edited and add first part of source code.

Comment: Please format your code. Which simulator do you use?

Comment: I use Modelsim . What do you mean by formating the code ?

Comment: Your passing arguments to tasks that don't have input/output; that's not allowed. Is this in the same module? A task should only be called within its module. Do you want something synthesizable?

Comment: @W5VO formatted and indented your code lines. So now we can read them all. Normally, it's your task to present a good structured and readable question.

Comment: @Greg The task codes is in another module but I included the file name in the main module . Why they should be in the same module when I used "include" ? Actually the file compiled successfuly but I get this error when I want to simulate it using Modelsim !

Comment: @Paebbels this is saeeds first question. An effort to format the code* was* made, but it didn't completely work.

Comment: A nested module (module defined in another module) is not legal Verilog. SystemVerilog allows it, but it is not common practice. I supersized your code compiles. I suggest using your favorite search engine for "verilog coding style" and read up. There are a couple of reference links in my profile too.

Comment: @Greg Thanks , but I defined second module on another file and used this : `include "countmode_1.v"  , I defined tasks In module countmode and instant them in the main module . Actually defined tasks in module . Is this wrong  ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Greg pointed out, you are passing **more number of arguments** to tasks than required.

Also, including a file doesn't mean having access to all the tasks and functions inside the module. You have to **instantiate** the module inside your main `a8bitCounter` module as follows:

```
// `include "countmode_1.v" // include this file outside module will be good.
module a8bitCounter(inp[7:0], ocrn, counter[7:0]);
// ...
// ...
`include "countmode_1.v" // including here is not a common practice
countmode c1(); // instantiate the module
// ...
// ...
c1.countmode1(); // note the hierarchy path to the task
c1.countmode2(); // note the hierarchy path to the task
c1.countmode2(); // note the hierarchy path to the task
// ...
// ...
endmodule
```

If your `countmode` module is not required, then *remove* it and after that, the tasks shall be declared in **global compilation unit scope**. By, this you can directly use task names while invoking them (no need of hierarchy then,since they'll be in global scope). However, you **must** provide some input/output arguments to these tasks.

For more information on instantiating module in verilog, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module) link. Tasks/functions in verilog can be found in [this](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~elias/verilog/verilog_manuals/chap_9.pdf) PDF.